# Assign consecutive numbers to numpy array locations satisfying certain condition

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

This Python script:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(8, 8)
b = np.full_like(a, -1)
n = 0

for i, val in np.ndenumerate(a):
  if val < 0.666:
    b[i] = n
    n += 1
```

creates array `b` with consecutive natural numbers in locations where `a < 0.666` (placeholder for an arbitrary condition) and `-1` otherwise. Is there a magic NumPy expression to produce the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(8, 8)
b = np.full_like(a, -1)

mask = a<0.666
b[mask] = np.arange(mask.sum())
print(a)
print(b)
```